# Limit Azure Sql Database to only be accessible from certain Azure App Service, in different regions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I'd like to configure my Azure Sql Database to only be accessible from certain Azure App Services. These App Services are in different regions than my DB.

What I've tried so far:

- **Firewall IP-restriction.** This "works", but doesn't provide much real security. Outbound IPs are shared between many App Services. It's trivial for a malicious user to create a new App Service with the same outbound IP.
- **VNet Service Endpoints.** This only works if the App Service and DB are in the same region.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with a private link?
I have a small environment with 2 app services and 1 DB, and the connection is being made by private link

If you have 2 different VNETs, try to do a peering so the VNETs can see the privante link

[Microsoft Docs- Private Link to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-sql-portal)